# Is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^{2n}}{1-z^{2n}}$ convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Is $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^{2n}}{1-z^{2n}}, \hspace{1cm} |z| < 1$$ convergent? I think it is convergent and tried expanding the denominator but did not get any result. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ratio test${}$?

Comment: How to find the $n$-th coefficient for this series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $|z_0|=r<1$, then
$$\left|\frac{z_0^{2n}}{1-z_0^{2n}}\right|\leq\frac{|z_0|^{2n}}{1-|z_0|^{2n}}
<2|z_0|^{2n}=r^{2n},$$
when $n$ is large enough!
(due to $\lim_{n\to \infty}|z_0|^{2n}=0$, then there exists  $N$ such that when $n>N$, we have $|z_0|^{2n}<\frac{1}{2}$.).
So the series $$\sum\left|\frac{z_0^{2n}}{1-z_0^{2n}}\right|$$ is convergent, 
$$\sum\frac{z_0^{2n}}{1-z_0^{2n}}$$ is absolutely convergent, hence convergent.

Comment: Is $\frac{|z_0|^{2n}}{1-|z_0|^{2n}}
<2|z_0|^{2n}$ true? I think not. Because that implies $|z|^{2n} < 1/2$.

Comment: because $\lim_{n\to \infty}|z_0|^{2n}=0$, then there exists  $N$ such that when $n>N$, we have $||z_0|^{2n}|<\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Oh yes! It is clear now.

Answer (score 1):

Write $a_n=z^{2n}/(1-z^{2n})$. Then
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=z^2\frac{1-z^{2n}}{1-z^{2n+2}}$$
which converges to $z^2$ whenever $|z|<1$.

Comment: Ratio test is only for positive series!

Comment: I got it. You had considered the series as $\sum a_n$. I was trying to see as $\sum a_n z^n$ as Lord shark the unknown also was trying to say in the comments. Now it is clear.

Comment: @Riemann And I think this too is a positive series

Answer (score 1):

If $|z|<1$ then $|z^{2n}|<1/2$
for all large enough $n$.
Therefore $ |1-z^{2n}| > 1/2$
for all large enough $n$
so the sum behaves like
$z^{2n}$
which converges for
$|z|<1$.